# Protect only a directory with htpasswd

Tags: apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I would like to protect the `protect-me-dir` directory with http password. I tried this code:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted area"
AuthUserFile /home/iterator/public_html/protect-me-dir/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

It works, but unfortunately it asks for the password everywhere, not just in `protect-me-dir`. How is it possible to protect **only** that directory?

If I put this code inside `<Directory "/home/iterator/public_html/protect-me-dir">...</Directory>`, I get Internal Server Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the `.htaccess` file in the directory you want to password-protect. It is a per-directory config file.